# UEFI Interactive shell virtualbox not run grubx64.efi from a physical usb device. Virtualbox does not start uefi bootloader from physical disk

Tags: boot, usb, virtualbox

UEFI Interactive shell virtualbox not run grubx64.efi from a physical usb device

**I need to start grub from virtualbox UEFI interactive shell**.

Running grubx64.efi does nothing, blanks out, and does not start grub.
The usb device works perfectly on a physical machine

[UEFI Interactive shell virtualbox not run grubx64.efi][1]

The virtual machine configuration if is:

```
    <VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.15-linux">
  <Machine uuid="{2aeceaf8-dd57-468a-93e1-c44d5c00b1ba}" name="multiboot" OSType="Other" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2022-02-03T16:45:16Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{7b745c5b-4cdb-49d7-a9de-ce4554ca5456}" location="/home/n7rc/Documentos/multiboot.vmdk" format="VMDK" type="Normal"/>
      </HardDisks>
      <DVDImages>
        <Image uuid="{78866b76-b5cb-4b7c-b4bd-882cacc6ad71}" location="/home/n7rc/Documentos/isos/ADRIANE-KNOPPIX_V7.2.0gCD-2013-07-28-EN.iso"/>
      </DVDImages>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="PowerOff"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="448,87,512,419"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Hardware>
      <CPU>
        <PAE enabled="true"/>
        <LongMode enabled="false"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="2048"/>
      <Firmware type="EFI"/>
      <Boot>
        <Order position="1" device="HardDisk"/>
        <Order position="2" device="None"/>
        <Order position="3" device="None"/>
        <Order position="4" device="None"/>
      </Boot>
      <Display VRAMSize="4"/>
      <VideoCapture screens="1" file="." fps="25"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false"/>
      <BIOS>
        <SmbiosUuidLittleEndian enabled="true"/>
      </BIOS>
      <USB>
        <Controllers>
          <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
          <Controller name="EHCI" type="EHCI"/>
        </Controllers>
      </USB>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="08002736A5D1" cable="true" type="Am79C973">
          <NAT/>
        </Adapter>
      </Network>
      <AudioAdapter driver="Pulse" enabled="true" enabledIn="false"/>
      <Clipboard/>
      <GuestProperties>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="es_ES" timestamp="1643906617397912000" flags=""/>
      </GuestProperties>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="IDE" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{7b745c5b-4cdb-49d7-a9de-ce4554ca5456}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have configured your VM to use UEFI instead of BIOS?  Can post the relevant section from the VM's configuration file

Comment: Yes, UEFI is enabled, I incorporated the virtual machine settings. Thank you.

Comment: Just to check, what if you run or try to boot to External Shell as an external efi app https://github.com/pbatard/UEFI-Shell/releases/download/21H2/UEFI-Shell-2.2-21H2-RELEASE.iso and check if that succeeds? If so what if you run the same grub from that external shell?

Comment: You also cannot boot the provided external shell from a virtual optical drive. It must be a problem with the VIrtualBox and VirtualBox shell.

Comment: Only x64 is applicable. Others will be anyways unsupported. What I mean is can you boot to external shell bootx64.efi from Pen drive in Virtualbox? I do not know if Virtualbox supports external pen drive UEFI boot. If it does then what if you run grub from that external shell?

Comment: The external shell if I can run it from virtualbox, but the external shell does not run grub either. Thanks for your help. Yes, I knew it was only for x64 architecture.

Comment: Fixed installing grub for efi with --uefi-secure-boot option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed installing grub for efi with --uefi-secure-boot option.

```
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --recheck --removable --uefi-secure-boot --efi-directory=/efi_esp_mount --boot-directory=/data_mount/boot/
```